# Reducing the dimensions of a 4D feature tensor from ResNet to fit into a 2D LSTM model

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am designing a machine learning model that takes a feature tensor from ResNet and uses an LSTM to identify the sequences of letters in the image. The feature tensor that's from ResNet is 4-D , however, LSTM_cell wants inputs that are 2-D. I know about other methods such as .view() and .squeeze() that are able to reduce dimensions. However, it seems as if I do this, it changes the size of the dimensions of the feature vectors. At first the vector is [128, 2, 5, 512] but it needs to be [128, 512]. However, calling .view(-1,512) multiplies the dimensions to get [1280, 512]. How would you change dimensions without multiplying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outputs of CNN should be a 3-D Tensor (e.g. `[128, x, 512]`) so that it can be treated as a sequence. Then you can feed them into `nn.LSTMCell()` with an **x-iteration** for-loop.

However, 4-D Tensor remains some spatial features and it is not appropriate to be fed into LSTM. A typical practice is to redesign your CNN architecture to make sure that it produces a 3-D Tensor. For example, you can add an `nn.Conv2d()` or something else at the end of CNN network to make the outputs as shape `[128, x, 512]`.

Comment: Not sure how you expect a conv2d to output a 3D tensor...

Comment: @Ivan After adding an `nn.Conv2d()`, the outputs may be as a shape `[128, x, 1, 512]`. Then squeeze the width `1`. Besides, fully-connected layer is also practical.

Comment: But reasoning with shapes only won't suffice, conv2d are spatially applied on the input, so it makes little sense to reduce the first spatial location. This is IMO not a desirable solution.

Comment: @Ivan However, [someone](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.01906) really did it like this and it looks like practical. Perhaps there's another way to make it more reasonable but that's just what I know.

Answer (score 2):

As a side note: what you are trying to achieve has nothing to do with changing the shape of your tensor. Both [`torch.view`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.view.html) and [`torch.squeeze`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.squeeze.html) have no affect on the underlying data contained by the tensor but act solely on the *apparent* layout of the tensor, *i.e.* its shape, while the data remains the same.

All those reshaping operators ([`torch.view`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.view.html), [`torch.reshape`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.reshape.html), [`torch.unsqueeze`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.unsqueeze.html), [`torch.squeeze`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.squeeze.html), [`torch.transpose`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.transpose.html), [`torch.permute`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.permute.html)) will keep the number of elements the same because the content of the tensor ***remains the exact same***.

In your case, you are trying to reduce the dimensionality of the tensor from `[128, 2, 5, 512]` to `[128, 512]`. Generally speaking, a Resnet would output a 3d tensor `(b, c)` after the classifier layer, but here I presume you still have spatial dimensions since it is 4d. Depending on what your output represents you can either feed it into a fully connected layer to reduce its dimensionality or max/average pool over some of the dimensions.